# previous data is entered along with new autocompletetextview

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have autocomletetextview andit gets json response from server .It works fine when text is entered one by one but when you enter text quickly .

It adds the value of each letter which is the last response to the list .I have tried the code below .How do I fix this? I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

BaseActivity:

```
public class SimpleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader ;
    Bitmap image;
    private DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions;

    public SimpleAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().build();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(activity)
        .threadPoolSize(2) 
        .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
        .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
        .build();

        imageLoader  = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    imageLoader.init(config);

        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(activity));
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1); // title
        TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2); // artist name
        TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView3); // duration
        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        title.setText(song.get("firstname"));
        artist.setText(song.get("lastname")); 
        duration.setText(song.get("time"));
        imageLoader.displayImage(song.get("link"), thumb_image, defaultOptions);

        return vi;
    }


}
```

**MainActivity**

```
    public class AutoCompleteTextViewActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher{
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        private TextView selection;
        private AutoCompleteTextView actv;


        SimpleAdapter adapter;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
           selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
           actv=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.actv);
           actv.addTextChangedListener(this);



        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            Suggest Suggestdetails=new Suggest();
         if(aList!=null){

          Suggestdetails.execute(); 
         aList.clear();
          } else{

         listView.setAdapter(adapter);
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

 }


        }

        public class Suggest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {
            @Override
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) {

                 String ResponseBody = null;

                try {


                    //geoaddress here 

                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/suggest.php");

                    // Add your data
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", actv.getText().toString()));


                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
                    String line = "0";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    reader.close();
                    String result = sb.toString();

                    Log.d("Fb tr",result);
                    // parsing data
                    return new JSONObject(result);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }



            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {




                if (result != null) {
                    // do something
    //              JSONObject tr = result;

            List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

                try{
                  JSONArray arr=result.getJSONArray("Array");


                for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject e1 = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                    JSONObject json= (JSONObject) e1.get("data");

                    String firstname = json.getString("firstname").trim();  
                    String lastname = json.getString("lastname").trim();
                    String link = json.getString("link").trim();
                    String time = json.getString("time").trim();


                     HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
                        hm.put("firstname", firstname);
                        hm.put("lastname", lastname );
                        hm.put("link", link);
                        hm.put("time", time);
                        aList.add(hm);

                    }


                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }


                String[] from = { "firstname","lastname","time","link"};


                int[] to = { R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2,R.id.textView3,R.id.list_image};

                 adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AutoCompleteTextViewActivity.this,aList, R.layout.list_row,from,to);

                   actv.setAdapter(adapter);

                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                } else {
                    // error occured
                }
            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858843/how-to-dynamically-add-suggestions-to-autocompletetextview-with-preserving-chara

Comment: @pskink it has image also .And I posted the same query yesterday and you suggested Spannanble but then you checked and said that it wont work.

Comment: aaa it was you.... ok i will answer with my modified Cursor in ten minutes

Comment: Great Thanks the code below is not working.I am stuck real bad.

Comment: see my answer for your yesterdays question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code updated, I hope it run well :D
[Updated]

```
public class AutoCompleteTextViewActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        private TextView selection;
        private AutoCompleteTextView actv;

        List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        SimpleAdapter adapter;
        private Suggest Suggestdetails;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
            actv=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.actv);

            String[] from = { "firstname","lastname","time","link"};

            int[] to = { R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2,R.id.textView3,R.id.list_image};
            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AutoCompleteTextViewActivity.this,aList, R.layout.list_row,from,to);

            actv.setAdapter(adapter);

            actv.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if (Suggestdetails!=null && Suggestdetails.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)){
                Suggestdetails.cancel(true);
            }

            Suggestdetails=new Suggest();
            Suggestdetails.execute();
        }

        public class Suggest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<HashMap<String,String>>> {

            @Override
            protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(Void... params) {

                String ResponseBody = null;
                try {
                    //geoaddress here
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/suggest.php");

                    // Add your data
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", actv.getText().toString()));

                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
                    String line = "0";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");

                        if (isCancelled()) return null;
                    }
                    reader.close();
                    String result = sb.toString();

                    Log.d("Fb tr",result);
                    List<HashMap<String,String>> resultList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

                    if (isCancelled()) return null;

                    try{
                        JSONObject resultJson = new JSONObject(result);
                        JSONArray arr=resultJson.getJSONArray("Array");
                        for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject e1 = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                            JSONObject json= (JSONObject) e1.get("data");

                            String firstname = json.getString("firstname").trim();
                            String lastname = json.getString("lastname").trim();
                            String link = json.getString("link").trim();
                            String time = json.getString("time").trim();


                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
                            hm.put("firstname", firstname);
                            hm.put("lastname", lastname );
                            hm.put("link", link);
                            hm.put("time", time);
                            resultList.add(hm);

                            if (isCancelled()) return null;

                        }
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return resultList;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String,String>>... result) {
                if (result != null) {
                    aList.clear();
                    aList.addAll(result[0]);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    // error occured
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code is not working at postexecute.I dont see any data in dropdown when adapter is set and data notified after async .Please look into it.Thanks

Comment: I have updated code. I was missing at onPostExecute's parametes.

Comment: I am getting this error `The method onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String,String>>...) of type AutoCompleteTextViewActivity.Suggest must override a superclass method`